# Semi-Monthly Date Calculation in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to do calculations on date using "Semi-Monthly". How many days in semi month? AddMonths (0.5) does not work :)

```
Console.WriteLine("SemiMonthly : " + date.AddMonths(0.5)); //This does not work
```

Comment: What is half of a month? How many days, 14, 15 or even 15.5?

Comment: How would define "semi-month"? It's hard enough with full months. Seriously, why are you trying to do this? What's the context?

Comment: Semi-Monthly = At intervals twice monthly... what are the intervals?

Comment: I cant do with assuming 15 and add 15 days.. the month may contain 30 days, 31 days, 28 days or 29 days...

Comment: Have you tried that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481517/how-many-days-to-add-for-semi-monthly?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Of course `.AddMonths(0.5)` won't work because it receives an `int` variable.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that adding half of a month means according to this month, then you could do:

```
public static DateTime AddHalfMonth(DateTime dt, MidpointRounding rounding)
{
    int daysInMonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);
    if(daysInMonth % 2 == 0)
        return dt.AddDays(daysInMonth / 2);
    else if(rounding == MidpointRounding.ToEven)
        return dt.AddDays(daysInMonth / 2);
    else
        return dt.AddDays((daysInMonth + 1) / 2);
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
DateTime inHalfMonth = AddHalfMonth(date, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

Comment: Add a `this` before the `DateTime dt` in the signature, and you can use it as `inHalfMonth = date.AddHalfMonth(MidpointRounding.ToEven);`. Add a sensible default to the `rounding` parameter and it gets even nicer.

Comment: @anaximander: i don't like the idea of making everything an extension even if you use this method only at few places.  That "pollutes" intellisense. But if you find this useful feel free to add `this` ;)  By not making `rounding` an optional parameter i just wanted to force OP to think about it.

Comment: Both valid points; as with many things it depends on the usage. If you're frequently adding a half-month and you're doing it in multiple places, then an extension method makes it simpler to do so (just watch what namespace it's in, so it's only visible where you need it to be). If it only happens a few times, or in a particular place, then it makes more sense as a class-level function the way you've written it. Likewise, whether or not to add a default rounding option depends on how often you'd want to use a different option, and how bad it is to get the wrong one.

Answer (score 3):

If you want, you can add half days of the current month by doing this:

```
DateTime a = new DateTime();
a.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(a.Year, a.Month)/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to define what exactly "semi-monthly" means, and in doing so, you'll answer your own question.

For simplicity, I would suggest you just use the first and 15th of each month.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define your own convention for this - there is no canonical notion of a "half month".

Comment: _Well_, yes. But this wouldn't be better as a comment?

Comment: @SonerGönül The question was "How many days in semi month?", so isn't the answer "You decide." valid? In fact, any specific code becomes a suggested convention, and I wouldn't want to presume. The choice of convention here is the most important point, and I don't want to obscure that.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed some concepts from Tim's answer but the additional logic allows for a schedule to never deviate from the half-month mark. I had noticed that if I ran the function recursively starting from Jan 16 the 24th item was ending up Dec 20-something. I've simplified the function and made it an extension.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime AddHalfMonth(this DateTime dt)
    {
        int daysInMonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);
        if (daysInMonth % 2 == 0 || dt.Day < daysInMonth / 2)
        {
            return dt.AddDays(daysInMonth / 2);
        }

        return dt.AddDays((daysInMonth + 1) / 2);
    }
}
```